# how can i display this data from an api which is in format of json and array

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

What i want to achieve is to display this data in a dashboard for example risk name how many they are etc i using laravel
how can i fetch it and display it to the blade

```
https://portal.zebratop.co.ke/api/v1/powerbi/dashboards/risk
```

this what i a have tried

```
    public function index()
    {
        $Total_users = User::all();

        $response = Http::acceptJson()
            ->get('https://portal.zebratop.co.ke/api/v1/powerbi/dashboards/risk');

        if($response->failed()){
            // Handle failure here
        }

        // Data was fetched successfully
        $data = collect($response->json());

        $data = $data->mapToDictionary(function($data, $key){
            $key = $data[0]['Business Unit'];
            //$key = $data[1]['Risk Name'];
            return [$key => $data];
        });
        
        $count = 0;

        $data = $data->map(function($data) use ($count){
            $count += count($data[0]);
            return $data[0];
        });
        //dd($data);

        // Pass the data to view
        return view('home',compact('Total_users','data'));
        //return view('view.name', compact('data'));
    }
```

this the blade

```
<tr>
    <th class="text-center" colspan="2"><h5 align ="center"><b>Business Unit</b>:{{$data->count()}}</h5></th>
</tr>
<tr>
     <th><h6><b>{{$data[Risk Name]}}</b></h6></th>
</tr>
```

Comment: First issue off the bat. `{{$data[Risk Name]}}` is `{{$data['Risk Name']}}`

Answer (score 0):

Try using curl to fetch the data from the endpoint.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://portal.zebratop.co.ke/api/v1/powerbi/dashboards/risk',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Im5sb0JHVTFjZUhkQ2xrRTl1Nlp5RFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSC9oYXZUMHZMSlpHa0sxbnBrUW12a2o2K014S25Ba2dmSzY3cDIwWWF5M2lwWXdDRnAvbHVmYXZMbnM4SitNeEtrdXQ2V2pucUxzdWFwa2dJWGZ5c2hHZ0I0L0NrV1hTZjNTRWZvOVRidzZ2SE5wbVFRcVhsenF4b3A4NFA3VUIiLCJtYWMiOiI2Y2EyM2ZjZDQzNWFjNjYzYjU1NTg0ZjI3Y2UwYjdhYzM1NmUwYmNhZGExZjViMmRlMTBiMTAyM2ViMDFmMzZhIn0%3D; risk_management_system_session=eyJpdiI6IkpKK215cktjWlc0Q1VWbnVxNmN4UUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZU9YbXhRUTdIQ2t5OEV5dWw2ZVJXT2lHMnBGSXhBMk9WSFhuS3pTbVhRTWRPZTFrUHRLMGo0Z1Y0aGMrZ25tZ2JkeXRrRi92WTUzMFRYTXhxVG9pWDQwN3JzQiszcnVkUTFzVGk3RDNJSHB3UWpjV1VPTEF6Zk54VDhxRGdDSEsiLCJtYWMiOiJlZmQ4MGM0NmI2M2YwN2FmOTkyODcxYTliY2RjZjI4ZWZlY2ZjYWIzZjE0ODBjY2M1MzM5MzNmNjU0MjRjNjJiIn0%3D'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Then use json_decode($response) to convert into php array.

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
return view('home',compact('Total_users','data'));
```

To

```
return view('home', ['data' => $data]);
```

Now you can access $data in blade file.
eg. `$data["Risk Name"]`.
if data is array of object then `$data[0]["Risk Name"]`

Comment: still not working

Comment: using the example you gave me`ErrorException
Undefined index: Risk Name` `{{ $data["Risk Name"] }}`

Comment: I think you are passing array of object from controller in $data variable.